# Argument passed by value appears as passed by reference in the debugger in Visual Studio 2010, C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm currently debugging a project I've been working on for a while, and, as I wanted to know the content of a QString named file, and thus wrote file.d in my watched variables, I just noticed that file was actually an address.

The thing is, file was not an address in my code.

Here is the function I was in :

```
void MyClass::updateFile(QString file, QTreeWidgetItem *item)
{
   if(file.isEmpty())
      return;
    QFile f(file); // Line were I had the breakpoint
...
}
```

So I checked the stack and it was really written

```
updateFile(QString *file, QTreeWidgetItem *item)
```

I first thought of a compiler optimization, but since I was in debug mode, that seems unlikely.

Do you have an explanation ?

EDIT : I must add that when I changed the signature to

```
void MyClass::updateFile(QString const &file, QTreeWidgetItem *item)
```

The problem disappears and debugger and code have the same signature again.

Comment: `void MyClass::updateFile(QString file, QTreeWidgetItem *item)` and `void MyClass::updateFile(QString *file, QTreeWidgetItem *item)` are two different functions, due to function *overloading*.

Comment: Also, the internal data of many framework classes (like `QString`) might not be exactly what you think it might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing by value/reference is a C++ aspect. At the assembly level, a big structure might still be copied somewhere and passed by pointer. Its the C++ semantics that you are working on a duplicate, but assembly cannot pass by value all sorts of structs.

Comment: Shouldn't the debugger hide this ? As it's meant to help finding errors in the code, it's quite surprising that it shows this kind of internal manipulation.

Comment: Well, your debugger is quite old, try VS 2019.